# Inherit a class and apply a parameter automatically in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have around 300 functions and don't want to have to make a wrapper for each of them.

```
class B
{
    func(vartype somevar, int otherparam)
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

Then I want to do this

```
class A:B(vartype somevar)
{
    Asfunc2()
    {
        this->func(1);  //basically somevar would already be filled in when called and it'd just need the 1 param.
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you wrapping here? And what `apply parameter` means? Pass some default instance of object?

Comment: 300 functions in a single class sound like the class has more than one responsiblity and therefore can be considered as bad design...

Comment: is the `somevar` the same for all the functions?

Comment: @Matten agree. Usually you should not have more than 10-20 methods in class. And they should be small.

Comment: The methods are in a DLL I'm accessing. @happygilmore yes, somevar is the same for all the functions and is always the first parameter

Answer (score 1):

You could call base constructor as follows:

```
public class Manager : Employee
{
    public Manager(int annualSalary)
        : base(annualSalary)
    {
        //Add further instructions here.
    }
}
```

The reference is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

What you described is looks like [binding function parameters in JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff841995%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) but it's not possible in C# as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about the situation you described and was using the following linqpad script to go over what this would imply:

```
void Main()
{
    B b = new B();
    b.CallA().Dump();
}


class A
{
    public string CallA(string someVar)
    {
       return string.Format("{0} says Hello", someVar);
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public string CallA(string someVar = null)
    {
       return base.CallA(someVar);
    }
}
```

You essentially end up with an overloaded CallA method.  This <s>can</s> will get sticky.  What about the following code that you would execute in the Main method after creating an instance of B:

```
((A)b).CallA();  //You actually want to call A.CallA
```

This still calls `b.CallA()`.

Just be careful. This does not feel like a good design.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to class B, then I believe the only way to do what you want is to make `somevar` a global variable, which will be initialized in the constructor.

You might be able to get around this with reflection, but it seems more likely you have a code smell, and the real problem is in the design, not the implementation.